# regex format string number with commas and 2 decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `n` which is a number.
The following adds the commas where needed, but I also want to change the number of decimals.  It should also round where appropriate.

```
var parts = n.split(".");
var num = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
```

This turns a number like `1234.567` in to `1,234.567`.
But I need my number to look like: `1,234.57`

I tried taking `parts[1]` and converting to a Number, then rounding, then concatenating it back; but that is error prone.

How can I get this result by altering my regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var val = Math.round(Number(n) *100) / 100;
var parts = val.toString().split(".");
var num = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
```

Answer (score 47):

**Edit: Sept 18, 2019**

Since new APIs are available, thought it would be helpful to point out that you can do this much more simply using [`toLocaleString` options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_options):

```js
const numbers = [1, 1000, 2345.67, 21589.334719999995];
const options = { 
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2 
};
numbers.forEach(num => {
  const formatted = Number(num).toLocaleString('en', options);
  console.log(formatted);
});
```

---

**original answer**

To add the commas, you could use:

```
n = parseFloat(n).toFixed(2)
var withCommas = Number(n).toLocaleString('en');
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUR7r/)

Comment: I collapsed the whole thing to `Number(parseFloat(n).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en');`

Comment: @RobM. But I tested with 123949.1, it does not return me with 2 decimal point. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: I tested with n=1. Returns 1, expected 1.00 (does not work :'( )

Comment: @daCoda Right, you would need to use the `maximumFractionDigits` option for that

Comment: This: Number(n).toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }). Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that 123949.1 becomes 123,949.1 which isnt 2 decimals

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [**toFixed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
var parts = (+n).toFixed(2).split(".");
var num = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (+parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LuY5R/2/)

That would also make `1234.0000` to `1234.00`, but you can avoid that by converting to a number in the ternary, as zero is falsy

Comment: n is a string, so I cant use toFixed(). n needs to stay a string for other reasons.

Comment: @brno792 - I'm sorry to break it to you, but you can't round a string, no matter how hard you try.

Comment: You could of course just slice of the end of the string with `parts[1].slice(0,2)`, but that would give you `1234.56` as it doesn't round.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that.. your solution is no help though.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is useful

```js
var n=1234.567
var parts = n.toFixed(2).split(".");
var num = parts[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + 
    (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
console.log(num);
```

if you want result `1,234.567` then change `toFixed(2)` to `toFixed(3)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var valueString="1500"; //can be 1500.0 or 1500.00 
var amount=parseFloat(valueString).toFixed(2);
var formattedString= amount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
console.log(formattedString); //outputs 1,500.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Typically, it's helpful to write a few remarks outside of the code block that explains how the code works for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to formatting currency in JavaScript, [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) is great.  You don't need to combine it with `toFixed` and it will not work in some cases (whole numbers, numbers with single-digit fractions).  Here's an example function:

```
const formatCurrency = (num, locale = 'en-US', currency = 'USD', minimumFractionDigits = 2) => {
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return num;
    }
  return num.toLocaleString(locale, {style: 'currency', currency, minimumFractionDigits});
};
```

No super-customized string format patterns and no chained methods that work in specific scenarios.

Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oob68ef1/)

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid that by converting to a number in the ternary, as zero is falsy**

```
n = parseFloat(n).toFixed(2)
var withCommas = Number(n).toLocaleString('en');
withCommas = (withCommas.indexOf(".")== -1) ? `${withCommas}.00` : withCommas;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @Rob M's answer (for a minimum AND maximum of 2dp):

```
function getMe2DecimalPointsWithCommas(amount) {
    return Number(amount).toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easy way to format the Number with different Locale

```
const NumberFormatter = (value, decimal) => {
  return parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(decimal)).toLocaleString(
    "en-IN",
    {
      useGrouping: true,
    }
  );};
```

Instead of "en-IN" you can specify Language. like ‘ja-JP’,’en-US’ and ‘de-DE’, etc.
It will group the number with the symbol based on the locale.

Ref: [Format Numbers](https://medium.com/@noffybarudwale/javascript-format-numbers-with-commas-and-decimals-86b68ec5b180)