# Format textField value with comma - Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I have a textField value as 12345678955. I want to format this value as 1,234,567.8955

Want to seperate the value with comma.

I have tired with some codes. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Put here your code

Comment: Do u want to do it in ios or android?

Comment: In Titanium studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you would want to get your 4 decimal places you would need to divide your number by 10000:

```
var newNumber = parseInt($.yourTextField.value);
newNumber = Math.round(Number(newNumber)) / 10000;
console.log(newNumber); // 1234567.8955
```

Next you want to add your commmas:

```
var parts = newNumber.toString().split(".");
var num = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
console.log(num); // 1,234,567.8955
```

Thats the functionality, how you tie that to your textField and by which event listener, is yours to work out.

(answer adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25127753/829989 which you could have easily found on your own)

Comment: Great... Thanks for helping.