# What is the regex for converting an integer to price?

Tags: jquery, regex, integer, format

I need an integer converting to two decimals places and with commas.

I currently  have the following:

`/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"`

which out puts `9,999.9999999`

How do I change it to output the following:

`9,999.99`

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127054/regex-format-string-number-with-commas-and-2-decimals-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution 
`accounting.js` is a tiny JavaScript library for number, money and currency formatting.

[Check this for ref](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/#demo)

**OR**

Please use this JS function as your need

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: How do I apply this in jQuery to a div called `.output`?